# Help for decomposition of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I don't understand how from:

$$x^2 - 3x +2\sqrt{x}$$

You arrive at:
$$\sqrt{x}\hspace{0.2cm}(\sqrt{x}-1)^2\hspace{0.1cm}(\sqrt{x}+2)$$

Can someone show me the steps, please.

Comment: Let's use the substitution $t=\sqrt x$, thus you have to show $t^4-3t^2+2t=t(t-1)^2(t+2)$... Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take the transformation: $t = \sqrt{x}$, the equation becomes: $$F(t) = t^4-3t^2+2t = t(t^3-3t + 2) = t(t+2)(t^2-2t+1)$$ as we can factorise $t^3-3t+2$ using a simple trial and error method by checking $1$ and $2$ are its roots.